# What is the err parameter in OpenCv's Lucas Kanade method?

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

In the function `cv::caclOpticalFlowPyrLK(..)` there's a parameter `cv::OutputArray err`. What does this parameter specify? Is it the distance at which the corresponding match was found for a feature?
[Lucas Kanade | OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html)

This question arose because I checked the difference between `err[i]`, and the Euclidean distance of `prevPts[i]` and `nextPts[i]` and it turns out to be somewhere in the range -1 or +1, occasionally outside it.

Answer (score 1):

Optical flow basically works by matching a patch, around each input point, from the input image to the second image.

The parameter `err` allows you to retrieve the *matching* error (e.g. you may think of that as the correlation error) for each input point. As said in the documentation, the actual error measure depends on what flags were specified.

Comment: So, something like a confidence value?

Comment: Yes exactly. And the actual measure which is used is controlled by the `flags` parameter. An explanation is given in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk).

Comment: What I don't get, then, is how come the `err[i]` is so close to Euclidean distance between `prevPts[i]` and `nextPts[i]`?